# Docker build failed | The command '/bin/sh -c node -v' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295 on windows

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

This is a basic `Dockerfile` that I am trying to build on windows docker. `docker build . -t nishantt95/my-node-app`

```
FROM node:16.14.2

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Once it completes a `RUN` command, it prompts an error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c npm i' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295: failed to shutdown container: container 89916be2224207b5aab466b1582a44a59c3375330feb698408b758f7adbcb996 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call
: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): subsequent terminate failed container 89916be2224207b5aab466b1582a44a59c3375330feb698408b758f7adbcb996 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in
 a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)
```

Soon I realized that I am facing this error with all the basic `RUN` command (e.g. `RUN pwd`, `RUN node -v`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue building the container on windows, hence we need to switch to Linux containers.

[image]

**Note**: Windows might prompt you to install [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package) so install that and restart your docker desktop. After that, rebuild your `Dockerfile` and it will work as expected.